# GetWindowRect coordinates not screen-relative

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I am working in Visual Studio 2008 C++. I have an MFC dialog with a control inside it. I am trying to position another dialog in the control.

SetWindowPos() on the second dialog is clearly using screen coordinates, so I need to get the screen coordinates of the control or the parent dialog. The MSDN documentation says GetWindowRect() provides "screen coordinates relative to the upper-left corner of the display screen" but this is NOT what I am getting. On the control it gives coordinates relative to the parent. On the parent it gives left=0 and top=0. I have tried the rectangle from GetWindowPlacement() as well and it gives the same thing. Everything is relative to the parent.

Why is GetWindowRect() not returning screen-relative coordinates? Is there another way to get them?

I'm not new to programming, but fairly new to Windows programming, Visual Studio, and MFC, so I may be missing something obvious.

Here is what I am doing in OnInitDialog for the parent dialog:

```
// TestApp message handlers

BOOL TestApp::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    FILE * pFile = fopen("out.txt","w");
    CRect winRect;
    GetWindowRect(&winRect);
    fprintf(pFile,"left=%li top=%li right=%li bottom=%li\n",winRect.left,winRect.top,winRect.right,winRect.bottom); fflush(pFile);
    fclose(pFile);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

When run, the dialog does NOT appear at the upper-left corner of the screen, but out.txt contains:

```
left=0 top=0 right=297 bottom=400
```

Comment: Never! GetWindowRect never returns any relative coordinates. You get always screen coordinates. Show us your code to clarify this!

Comment: Instead of describing, show your code.  Too many times a poster will claim they are doing "this and that" and turns out they're not doing what they claim.

Comment: If you are new to Windows programming, don't use a framework that requires intimate knowledge of the Windows API (like MFC does). Instead, get to know the Windows API first. It's both easier to learn and understand, as well as more direct in its effects. [Learn to Program for Windows in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399.aspx) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the other answer:

OnInitDialog is called **before** the window is moved to its final position. If you call GetWindowRect later you'll see it return the proper coordinates.

Just use PostMessage with a WM_APP+n message. This message will arrive when the message pump is running and the message will arrive when the window is positioned and shown on the screen.

Or use a timer. This has the same effect.

Comment: Posting a message to yourself is not a solution. Posted messages are received by a window in a strict FIFO order. If you post your message too early, it will be handled too early. You would have to post the message immediately after the system has posted its `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message. Since you don't know when the system does, you're back to square one. Using a timer, on the other hand, has a very different effect: Low priority messages are moved to the back of the message queue, and a window only receives them when no posted messages or input messages are available.

Comment: WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED is sent with SendMessage. It isnot sent via the message queue. So there is no FIFO! Any message sent with SendMessage will arrive before the message pump of the dialog starts. Just set a breakpoint and look into the call stack! And because the window shows up before the message loop starts everything is done...

Comment: @IInspectable: My code using PostMessage WM_APP+n works perfectly. The window Position is set when the message arrives. There is no Need to post this message in WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED! It is sufficient to do it in WM_INITDIALOG.

Comment: Your code stops working for a window that decides to postpone window positioning negotiations and bails out the first time it receives a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message, for example. Your proposed solution is convoluted, hard to understand and document, and has a tendency to become unmaintainable in no time. If you want to respond to window positioning changes, do it in your `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message handler. Simple as that.

Comment: :) yes, but this wasn't the question! And the question was not: "Get me the real window ycoord all the time..." Also you told me that my solution didn't work at all. But it does. Also you notes (about FIFO) will not touch my solution. And yes my soltion may not work in the situition you are mentioning. And why isN#t id hard to understand. Write one comment line.  OK we stop discussing here...

Comment: I didn't claim that your solution never worked. I outlined why it doesn't work **reliably**, and that it's unnecessarily hard to get right, and unnecessarily hard to maintain. A clean, reliable solution exists.

Answer (score 2):

[`OnInitDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59.aspx) is called by the framework, before the dialog is shown. At this point, neither the final size nor position are known:

> Windows sends the WM_INITDIALOG message to the dialog box during the [Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd.aspx), [CreateIndirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye1hz8we.aspx), or [DoModal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx) calls, which occur immediately before the dialog box is displayed.

The final size and position of a dialog are the result of window positioning negotiations. The first message sent to a dialog where this information is available is [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652.aspx). Using MFC, this message is handled through [`CWnd::OnWindowPosChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs9c0kfx.aspx). Custom handling code can be implemented by overriding `OnWindowPosChanged` in your `CDialog`-derived class.

Comment: @xMRi: Nothing in the question states, that the application wants to be notified only once. If that additional requirement exists, I'm sure even you could solve the challenge of storing state information across calls. In all, that's a pretty lame explanation for downvoting an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`OnInitDialog` is called *before* the window is moved to its final position. If you call `GetWindowRect` later you'll see it return the proper coordinates.

Comment: Is there an OnSomething function I can put this in so that it is called immediately after the window is moved to its final position? I looked through CWnd member functions but I can't tell which to use.