# Why would GetWindowRect() obtain weird coordinates for tray item popups?

Tags: windows, user-interface, winapi, visual-c++, screen

MSDN says `GetWindowRect()` returns screen coordinates for window. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26220252/57428) explains how a dialog is first shown at screen top left corner and then positioned elsewhere so until it's properly positioned `GetWindowRect()` would return (0,0)..(width,height).

Here's what I see. There's a console program running an infinite loop with each iteration calling `GetForegroundWindow()` and then `GetWindowRect()` for the obtained window. For most of the windows coordinates obtained look realistic.

However if I run `Task Manager` it adds a tray icon (near the system clock) and if I right-click that icon I get a popup with `Close` and `Always on top` items. While that popup is active `GetForegroundWindow()` would repeatedly return a window with `TrayiconMessageWindow` window class which makes sense. However when `GetWindowRect()` for that window is called it would succeed and obtain a rect with `left` and `top` set to zero and `right` and `bottom` set such that a reasonably small rectangle is produced.

The popup is displayed somewhere near the right bottom corner so I would expect a rectangle like (1000, 1000)..(1100, 1050) but I actually get (0,0)..(100,50) rectangle.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `TrayiconMessageWindow` would seem to suggest that this is a [message-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows) window. To answer the question what you are doing wrong you would have to explain why you are collecting this information in the first place.

Comment: @IInspectable How is it possible to have a visible window which is a message-only window?

Comment: A message-only window is invisible by definition.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, that's why I'm surprised. I do see the popup.

Comment: Have you verified that the window you see is the same as the one referenced by the handle returned from `GetForegroundWindow`?

Comment: "*There's a console program running an infinite loop with each iteration calling GetForegroundWindow() and then GetWindowRect() for the obtained window*" - repeated polling is not a good idea.  I would suggest a hook instead, either via `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()`. Let the OS *notify* you when the foreground window changes, when a window changes position, etc.

Comment: The popup menu is not the foreground window. Foreground is an invisible window that owns the popup menu